# WP adds margin to float

Tags: css-float, wordpress-theming, firebug, margins

sorry to bother you but this is getting me crazy :(

im fixing the wordpress theme of this site: http://hotel-garage.com.mx/blog/, everything its ok until you select a post (i.e. http://hotel-garage.com.mx/blog/2013/04/12/los-claveles-las-noches-no-son-para-dormir/) in there you can see the post but its moved to the right for about 50px, pushing the side bar down

I have been searching the CSS declaration that causes this using firebug, but i cant find it

Can you help me to locate the cause of the problem and how to correct it?

regards...

Comment: Almost everything, set margins, padding 0, remove js and css to try to find if that was the cause of the missaligment, set overflow hidden, even to un-float the content, but that screws all the rest of the site....

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're just trying to fit too much stuff into too narrow a space.

If you drop the width of your `<div id="left-area">` down to 630px (style.css line 133), then the sidebar has room to come up.

Drop the `padding-left` style from your `#entries` style (style.css line 725) so that post images don't overlap the sidebar.

You'll also need to shrink your post header-image so it doesn't overlap your sidebar: add `max-width:630px;` to your `.single-thumb` styles (style.css line 779).

Comment: That did help me a lot, i just upload some of your suggestions mixed with some others, but i still wanted to find why a div with doesnt float all to the left